# Multiple Instances Of JavaApplication

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Is it possible to run more than one instance of a JavaApplication developed in Netbeans? 
My project uses sockets and I need multiple instances of my application to test it. 
Before Netbeans I used Eclipse which allows me to run more instances by clicking two or three times on the "run"-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the project and then run the jar multiple times :

> java -jar ../dist/Project.jar

To answer specifically to you question : yes you can , just hit `F6` multiple times (number hits = number instances)

Comment: F6 doesn't work for me with Mac OS X. After one hit the function which is connected to F6 is disabled and the "forbidden"-sound appears...

Comment: Then try pressing multiple times the Run button (play) , on mac os you probably have a different shortcut